# WinAPI - right mouse drag & drop and IContextMenu

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, com

When a user right-clicks and drags a file into a different directory, they are presented with a small context menu that includes entries such as **Copy here** and **Move here**:

[image: popup]

Is there a way to query these menu items yourself?

I was able to trigger the default implementation for this right drag-and-drop popup by following these steps:

- Register your app with `RegisterDragDrop`.
- In the `IDropTarget::Drop` method:

  - Obtain the `IShellFolder` interface for the drop path.
  - Get the `IDropTarget` interface from this folder.
  - Forward the `IDataObject` to the `DragEnter` and `Drop` methods.
  - The `Drop` method will display the correct context menu.

Here's the simplified version of the code:

```
HRESULT Win_DragDropTargetDrop(IDropTarget *iTarget, IDataObject *iData, DWORD keys, POINTL cursor, DWORD *effect)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    IShellFolder *folder = null;
    IDropTarget *folderDropTarget = null;
    POINTL pt = {0};

    hr = Win_GetIShellFolder(hwnd, dragDropPath, &folder);
    hr = folder->lpVtbl->CreateViewObject(folder, hwnd, &IID_IDropTarget, &folderDropTarget);
    hr = folderDropTarget->lpVtbl->DragEnter(folderDropTarget, iData, MK_RBUTTON, pt, effect);
    hr = folderDropTarget->lpVtbl->Drop(folderDropTarget, iData, MK_RBUTTON, pt, effect);
}
```

However, what I want is to enumerate these items within `IContextMenu` myself, using functions such as `CreatePopupMenu`, `QueryContextMenu`, and then iterating through that menu via `GetMenuItemCount` and `GetMenuItemInfo`.

The reason is that I'm rendering the context menu myself (instead of using the Windows built-in UI framework). I'm already doing this for the regular right-click context menu on a directory background.

[image: context menu]

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What do mean by "items" in "Is there a way to query these items yourself" and "enumerate these items myself"? If you mean the shell namespace items being dragged and/or dropped, IDataObject contains the list of items (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cfstr_shellidlist)

Comment: No, I meant iterating items within the context menu. I've edited the original question to convey this in a clearer manner.

Comment: Isn't that when you inspect the `IDataObject` that the user is dragging over your application, enumerate its contents, and tailor your popup menu based on what they're about to drop?

Comment: @IanBoyd the IDataObject only holds the item's content, not its menu. You have to ask the OS to render the menu for the item. You do that by querying the item for its IContextMenu and have it render to your own HMENU. Raymond Chen has a series of blog articles on working with IContextMenu

Comment: But iirc, you don't need to use Window's helper function; you can inspect the items yourself and create your own menu. iirc Raymond's series was about when you're creating a shell extension, or context menu handler, rather than simply being a drop target.

Comment: This menu is completely owned by the Shell, I don't think there's any way to create it from outside. However some custom menu handlers do appear in there (like 7-zip) so you could register one and be called, but it's a hackish.